# Spring + Hibernate bean declaration error

Tags: hibernate, spring

```
  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
<property name="mappingResources">
  <list>
    <value>product.hbm.xml</value>
  </list>
</property>
<property name="hibernateProperties">
  <value>
    hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
  </value>
</property>
```

I have this configuration in my applicationContext.xml file

However I get this error when I try to run my application:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in
>   ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
>   Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not
>   instantiate bean class
>   [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException

So it seems like it's not recognizing the class `LocalSessionFactoryBean`. However I when type, `import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean;`, eclipse doesn't complain.

Does anybody have an idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the key is this line:

> ```
> nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> ```
>
> org/dom4j/DocumentException

I would check the classpath to ensure that `dom4j` is there.

Answer (score 1):

Yep there is a `dom4j-1.6.1.jar`